# Increment sum range by 1 based on day of month

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, spreadsheet

not entirely sure how to word this but I shall give it my best attempt.

This is the general structure of my spreadsheet.

```
  | A   |B      |
-----------------
1 | Jan |       |
2 | 1   | £3.00 |
3 | 2   | £4.00 |
4 | 3   | £5.00 |
5 | 4   | £0.00 |
6 | 5   | £1.00 |
..| ... | ..... |
```

I want to do a sum function based upon the day of the month. The `A` Column includes the day of the month. I want to check the current day of the month, then match it to the value in the column `A`, then sum from `B2` until the `B` value adjacent to the current day of the month.

For example, if it's the 3rd of the month I want the formula to be `B2:B4`. Wasn't sure if I could do something like increment the day by 1, so for the 3rd day of the month the value would be `4` which could correspond to the cell at the end of the range `B4`.

Initially, I had this, but to do this for every day of every month seems a little verbose and wasn't sure if there is a more efficient option?

```
=IF(DAY(TODAY()) = 1, SUM(B2), 
IF(DAY(TODAY()) = 2, SUM(B2:B3), 
IF(DAY(TODAY()) = 3, SUM(B2:B4), 
IF(DAY(TODAY()) = 4, SUM(B2:B5), 
IF(DAY(TODAY()) = 5, SUM(B2:B6), 0)))))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the value of `DAY(TODAY())` as the `height` parameter of `OFFSET` to achieve this:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(B2,0,0,DAY(TODAY()),1)
```

Answer (score 1):

=SUM(INDIRECT("B2:B" & MATCH(DAY(TODAY()),A2:A100)))

The match gives you the row for today, then we concatenate it into an address and then the indirect passes that to the sum function

Answer (score 1):

```
=SUM(B2:INDEX(B2:B32,DAY(TODAY())))
```

Alternative format to get the range.  It assumes a maximum day of 31.